# How to divide several lists together while maintaining order?

Tags: python, list, division, divide

I am trying to create a three list (one contain average values for blue change, another for the green channel, and the last one for the red channel). However, I am having trouble dividing these three list together.

Here is a small example of what I am trying to achieve

```
a = [4,2,2,3]
b = [4,2,1,4]
c = [3,2,1,2]
result = [(4/4/3), (2/2/2), (2/1/1), (3/4/2)]
```

But here is the code:

```
c_1 = [img2[92, 72]]
c_2 = [img2[260,76]]
c_3 = [img2[422,79]]
c_All = [img2[92, 72],img2[260,76],img2[422,79]]

bAvgWells = []
gAvgWells = []
rAvgWells = [] 

for center in c_All:
    b = img2[center[0]-22: center[0]+22, center[1]-26: center[1]+26, 0]
    g = img2[center[0]-22: center[0]+22, center[1]-26: center[1]+26, 1]
    r = img2[center[0]-22: center[0]+22, center[1]-26: center[1]+26, 2]
    bAvg = np.mean(b)
    gAvg = np.mean(g)
    rAvg = np.mean(r)
    #Add each value from loop into list in line 54-56
    bAvgWells.append(bAvg)
    gAvgWells.append(gAvg)
    rAvgWells.append(rAvg)

avg_one = []
color_avg = []
end_b = len(bAvgWells)
end_f = len(avg_one)
#Divdes the list together for averages of all columns
for i in range(end_b):
    a = (bAvgWells[i]/gAvgWells[i])
    avg_one.append(a)
for k in range(end_f):
    b = (a[i]/rAvgWells[i])
    color_avg.append(b)
print (color_avg)
```

Error: "Mean of empty slice"

Comment: It would really help if you posted the entire error message, _including the line of code where the error happens_.

Comment: Also, `print b, g, r` with appropriate spacing -- just before you try to take their means.  `center` is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This begs for a functional approach:

```
>>> from functools import reduce, partial
>>> import operator
>>> a = [4,2,2,3]
>>> b = [4,2,1,4]
>>> c = [3,2,1,2]
>>> list(map(partial(reduce, operator.truediv), zip(a, b, c)))
[0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 2.0, 0.375]
```

Or expressing the same thing using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [reduce(operator.truediv, z) for z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> results = zip(a, b, c)
[(4, 4, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (3, 4, 2)]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [np.mean(sequence) for sequence in results]
[3.6666666666666665, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333, 3.0]
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> map(np.mean, zip(a, b, c))
```

As a named function:

```
import numpy as np

def find_averages(*inputs):
    return [np.mean(sequence) for sequence in zip(*inputs)]

print find_averages(a, b, c)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[3.6666666666666665, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333, 3.0]
```